# Permutations on function's argument

Tags: matlab, permutation

I am working on a project in matlab:
I need to call a function using all different possible **permutations** of arguments.
The problem is the arguments are arrays of different sizes.
I tried searching on the internet for permutations of the reference of the matrices, and found nothing.

```
function [ out ] = find6cyc( a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6 )
%UNTITLED12 Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here

out = fdcycmat(a1,a2);
out = fdcycmat(out,a3);
out = fdcycmat(out,a4);
out = fdcycmat(out,a5);
out = fdcycmat(out,a6);

end
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use Lists:

```
l = {a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6};
lperms = perms(l); % all permutations of the arrays
```

and change the function to accept a list of matrices

Comment: The `l` variable you define is not a list, it's a cell array